# Replace string with dynamic value

Tags: java

I have pattern like '`{YY}-{MM}-{SEQNO}`'. I want to replace above string by dynamic value.

For example

```
{YY} with - 17 
{MM} with - 06
{SEQNO} WITH - 0001
```

What is the way to that in java?

Comment: `String.replaceAll()`

Comment: Actually, `String.replace()` is better, as it doesn't require regular expressions - this is more efficient and has less problems with special characters.

Comment: so the ouput must be ***{17}-{06}-{0001}*** or ***17-06-0001***   ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace()`.

```
String template = "'{YY}-{MM}-{SEQNO}'";
template = template.replace("{YY}", "17");
template = template.replace("{MM}", "06");
template = template.replace("{SEQNO}", "0001");
```

(Thanks to @RealSkeptic for improvements).

Comment: The replacement should include the braces. You don't want to get `{17}-{06}-{0001}`. Also, you probably don't want to replace the template itself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks. I wasn't sure if OP wanted the braces or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print like 17-06-0001 Use

```
System.out.printf("%S-%S-%S\n", ""+17, ""+06, ""+0001);
```

or 
If you want to print like 17-6-1 Use

```
System.out.printf("%d-%d-%d\n", 17, 06, 0001);
```

Comment: What do you do when the template is changed like `{MM}/{SEQNO}-/{YY}`?

Answer (score 0):

**method one(easier method):**

```
String a = "{YY}-{MM}-{SEQNO}";
a = a.replace("YY", "17").replace("MM", "06").replace("SEQNO", "0001");
System.out.println(a);
//Output:  {17}-{06}-{0001}
```

**method two:**

```
a = Pattern.compile("YY").matcher(a).replaceAll("17");
a = Pattern.compile("MM").matcher(a).replaceAll("06");
a = Pattern.compile("SEQNO").matcher(a).replaceAll("0001");
System.out.println("My Output is : " +a);
//Output:  My Output is : {17}-{06}-{0001}
```

**Method three:**

Have a look at [this question -without using `replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656523/replace-characters-in-a-string-without-using-string-replace-method).